# Activating a openMDAO virtual environment?

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line, openmdao, virtual-environment

I am trying to activate OpenMDAO 0.13.0 virtual environment using the reference documents listed in the website. See: http://openmdao.org/releases/0.13.0/docs/

But have encountered several problems. Although I have rechecked my installation process and system requirements, again and again, I am not sure if my environment is active.

> It should be if I am not mistaken- we can see `(root)` in the image
>   below.

At some stage, my command line seems to take the `\activate`  and `\deactivate`the commands, but it doesn't take any further codes to run in it.

I also tried the `testflo` command after installing testflo in python, but the results give results as:

> 0:pass, 0: fail and 0: skiped

The test listed [here](http://openmdao.org/releases/0.13.0/docs/getting-started/install.html), gives an error. See image below.

[image]

Can you post a step by step guide that is updated and a few sample codes to check if my environment is up and running?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I could be mistaken, but I think you have to say `openmdao test` not just `test` to run the openmdao test suite?

It's been a while since I worked with a 0.13.x install.

I suppose you could run the `python` interpreter interactively, and then attempt to import various things from within OpenMDAO?  If the imports succeed, the code is installed.

Comment: Openmdao test gives the same error. Would you please elaborate I am under the impression that 0.13.x is the current stable version.

Comment: The latest stable version of OpenMDAO is 1.7.1.  http://openmdao.org/openmdao-1-7-1/

Comment: Okay would you please add a link or two that would help me get started with this. I mean on a proper installation and setup.